# Class and ID Usage

Tags: html, css

After carefully scrutinizing multiple sources on the Internet, I've discovered that the relatively universal answer to the popular "classes vs ids" question is that ID's are unique identifiers, and an element can only have one ID and that each page can have only one element with that ID. And that classes are not unique, and can be used on multiple elements rather than a single one, and elements can have multiple classes. After concluding with this information, I've begun looking at the source code of popular websites such as CNN, Yahoo, W3Schools, etc. and have noticed that parts of a website that are only used one time still have classes. For example, logos of a website will be under a class, or even a navigation bar will be specified with a class, why is this if there is only one logo on the website or one navigation bar? Wouldn't it be more appropriate to utilize ID's for this matter? This question may seem silly to more experienced developers, but I hope to find some clarification in the answers. Thank you so much.

Comment: You only see one logo does not mean they only have one logo for the whole app, and in the future, you want to reuse that logo style? Also, the same logo style could be used to another icon like button or logo for another brand etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Classes and IDs are not mutually exclusive. Classes are primarily for CSS styling, while IDs *can* be for styling, but that's not the reason we generally add them initially. We add IDs so that the element(s) can be more easily accessed via JavaScript and manipulated dynamically.

Therefore it is very common to find elements with both an `id` and classes - - Each serving a different purpose.